# Why does changing user's "Primary Group" from "Domain Users" in Active Directory stymie a recursive search for users?

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory, ldap, directoryservices

Given the following simple OU/Group hierarchy:

```
OU=MyApplication
    CN=CompanyClients(objectClass="group"; Members="Clients\Client1")
    OU=Clients
        CN=Client1(objectClass="group"; Members=".\client1-emp1; .\client1-emp2")
        CN=client1-Emp1 (objectClass="user"; Primary Group="Client1")
        CN=client1-Emp2 (objectClass="user"; Primary Group="Domain Users")
```

Why will the following recursive search omit client1-emp1 simply because its primary group is not set to either "Domain Users" or "Domain Guests"? Also, what other groups can be set as the primary group so that emp1 is successfully included in the search?

```
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;

var ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "mydomain.org");
var group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, IdentityType.SamAccountName, "CompanyClients");

var results = group.GetMembers(recursive:true);
//results excludes client1-emp1 but includes client1-emp2
foreach (var principal in results)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Principal:" + principal.SamAccountName);
}
```

Results:

```
Principal: client1-emp2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check the "memberOf" property of an object in Active Directory (check e.g. your own account) you will see that it *does not* include your primary group (which is most likely "Domain Users"). You can see what is the primary group of a person by looking at the "primaryGroupID" property, which is "513" if your primary group is Domain Users.

Similarly, if you check the "member" property of "Domain Users", you *will not* see the people that have Domain Users as primary group.

I remember reading somewhere that this is done for performance reasons (of course now I cannot find the article), as having a group with too many members would impact performance under some circumstances.

Probably, the `GetMembers` method of `GroupPrincipal` does not search for users that have the group as primary group (i.e. it does not check the PrimaryGroupId attribute), that's why you don't see one of the members.

This article explains how to resolve the primary group for a user, I think you should be able to use the concepts explained here to solve your problem: [How to use the PrimaryGroupID attribute to find the primary group for a user](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/297951)

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks, Paolo! I noticed that it is doing something with the primary group via Resharper (i.e., ADStoreCtx.GetGroupMembership(GroupPrincipal g, bool recursive) ); however, I could not quite figure out how it was using it in its search.